# str(len(x)) in python

Tags: python

I was just starting to learn python, when I came around the odd notation I found on the web when searching for http request sending.

The length of the body of a http response (for the header) was determined with `str(len(body))`, which I found odd, since in my understanding is that `len(str(body))` is the intuitive notation (length of the string representation of the body)).

I'm really curious what this is about - Am I not getting a key concept of python here?

Why does Python use:

```
str(len(x))
```

Instead of:

```
len(str(body))
```

Comment: Okay -- stupid, stupid me. I forgot that the header in the http request consists of strings, which the "str" was for, of course. Thank you - this was nagging me ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the notation is correct; your interpretation of what is being computed is not.  This is computing the length of body (which is a string), and then yielding the string representation of that number.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct.  `len(str(body))` would be the same as just `len(body)`, because `body` is (presumably) already a string.  However, the result returned by `len` is a number (integer).  Python is relatively type-strict as dynamic languages go, and the code needed it as a string instead,so it called `str`.

e.g.:

```
>>> body = " This is the body" 
>>> len(body)      #    17
>>> str(len(body)) #    '17'
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you're understanding it correctly. It behaves like Java, C or most other languages.

That's computing the length of `body` and then casting it to a string. You will get back a numeric string.